# Having an issue getting a test to work using factory generated parameters verse literally including the parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following new and create actions that operate as expected (when I use the browser to perform the below task, things work):

```
def new
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @profile = @user.build_profile
end

def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @profile = @user.build_profile(params[:profile])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @profile.save
      format.html { redirect_to user_dashboard_path(@user, @user.dashboard), notice: 'Profile was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @profile }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @profile.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

However, I do not understand how to write a clean rspec test for the create action using my factories.

I have the following test that works:

```
before(:each) do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:admin)
  sign_in @user
end

it "creates a new Profile" do
  @profile = User.find(@user.id).build_profile #because this typically happens before in my 'new' action

  expect {
    post :create, :user_id => @user.id, :profile => {"first_name"=>"string",
     "middle_name"=>"string",
     "last_name"=>"string",
     "phone_number"=>"3213213211",
     "birth_date(1i)"=>"2013",
     "birth_date(2i)"=>"7",
     "birth_date(3i)"=>"4"}
  }.to change(Profile, :count)
end
```

Using this as my factory:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :profile do
    first_name "MyString"
    middle_name "MyString"
    last_name "MyString"
    phone_number 2108545339
    birth_date Date.new(1987,8,11)
  end
end
```

But I am declaring all of the parameters for the `post :create` action, which is messy.

It seems that there should be a way for me to pass in an object created by my factory instead of my explicit parameters - but I'm not sure how the syntax would work.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the purpose of the `@profile = ...` statement in the above, the comment notwithstanding, since you're not using the result in your test.

In any event, if it weren't for the fact that your parameters require separate fields for the birth date, you could create/use a `Profile` factory to create a profile object and then extract the attributes you need from the created profile using `.attributes.slice(:first_name, :middle_name, ...` or `.attributes.except(:id, ...)`.

However, given those three separate birth date fields, if you wanted to create the parameters through `FactoryGirl`, you'd have to define a separate class as in

```
class ProfileParameters
  attr_accessor :first_name, :middle_name, ..., :"birth_date(1i)", ...
end
```

Once you created your factory with appropriate parameter values, you could pass in FactoryGirl.create(:profileParameters)`for the`profile`parameter in your`post` call.

Comment: @Ecnalyr - Did I misunderstand your question or do see a problem with my answer?